# Trying to import psychopy on windows 10

Tags: python, importerror, psychopy

When I try to import the psychopy module into python 2.7, I get this error message:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event
```

ImportError: No module named psychopy

how can I give my copy of python access to this module. 
Any replies greatly appreciated, I'm sure that the answer should be something simple

Thanks!

Comment: did you install `psychopy` ? did you use `pip install psychopy` ?

Comment: http://psychopy.org/installation.html

Comment: http://psychopy.org/installation.html 

Windows (all versions):
    Download StandalonePsychoPy-1.84.2-win32.exe

Comment: i'm trying the install now thanks

Comment: is it as simple as just downloading it and installing it or do I have to link the two pieces of software in some way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/installing/index.html#installing-index

Comment: On Mac, PsychoPy comes with its own python. It is different from, say, the python that comes with OSX. As the answers above indicate, install `psychopy` in the python environment you plan on using.